How to construct input of solidity program that is fed into solana rbpf?
Get hello_sol.so
anchor init hello --solidity
anchor build

hello_sol.sol
@program_id("F1ipperKF9EfD821ZbbYjS319LXYiBmjhzkkf5a26rC")
contract hello_sol {
    bool private value = true;

    @payer(payer)
    constructor(address payer) {
        print("Hello, World!");
    }

    /// A message that can be called on instantiated contracts.
    /// This one flips the value of the stored `bool` from `true`
    /// to `false` and vice versa.
    function flip() public {
            value = !value;
    }

    /// Simply returns the current value of our `bool`.
    function get() public view returns (bool) {
            return value;
    }
}

Construct input
The input is the encoding of the function flip
5B3vFwFHgDL

Run in rbpf
./rbpf/cli/target/debug/rbpf_cli -u jit --mem 9999999999 --input ./solidity/sol/input --elf ./solidity/sol/hello_sol.so --trace

mem: [53, 66, 51, 118, 70, 119, 70, 72, 103, 68, 76]
Result: Err(AccessViolation(Load, 17179869200, 1, "input"))
Instruction Count: 46
Trace:


